# Not able to select page for spying the elements in blue prism

Tags: blueprism

I am trying to connect with Citrix application through my local window, I am able to handle all the Username/password and pop up(Security Windows) pages successfully. But after doing all these things, I reached at one browser based page (https://xxx.xxx.xx/dana-na/auth/url_43/welcome.cgi?p=user-confirm&id=state_7bfe65568e98f615f03a7322ec2ae248) and not able to "launch" or "attach" this page to spy the elements.

"launch" or "attach" will not work for this page because this whole path is changeable and can not be given as a default in application modeller.

I checked all the process (Task Manager) and found that this page creates 2 processes (parent and child) with target application "iexplore". And both parent and child process is having same name (I am assuming) because when I am giving window title of target application (let's say "Confirmation"), it is giving this error :

> "Error - Failed to launch application - Target application could not be identified".

And when target application is changed to "Confirmation*" getting this error: "Error - Failed to launch application - More than one application matched the criteria". Trust me, I checked all the processes and there was no other task running with this name "Confirmation".

Again to check the process, when I am aborting child or parent task both task is ended/disturbed.

Can anybody suggest here how to solve this situation? Have anyone ever faced this situation?

Comment: There is no trail code. This is one of the manual process in BluePrism RPA where I am trying to automate the browser based application. Could you please tell me which trail code you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you would have to use Surface Automation/Region mode to launch and navigate the apps within Citrix.

Comment: I tried to achieve surface automation abd region mode also but problem is, that browser page is not available for either “launch” or “attach”. And without detection of that page I cannot move ahead. Any other suggestions are also welcome, if you have any.

Comment: This is the correct answer - if you peruse the Blue Prism documentation at all you'll see that their official answer to anything Citrix is to use Surface Automation. Related readings/guides can be found on the Blue Prism portal: [Surface Automation | Blue Prism](https://portal.blueprism.com/learning/surface-automation)

Comment: fortunately i solved this issue. The issue was, after all the pop-ups it went to main page where it started from and unfortunately this page was not looking like the main page (All layout and elements of the page were changed, even the URL) . And in that page i was able to spy the elements.